# How to save/download generate QRCode inn react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, qr-code

By using this code  I am able to generate QRCode but , I don't know how to save that qrcode in png/jpeg format ono long press or automatic .
I need some help or idea  to solve that .. I tried few examples but not getting success . I am keep trying.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text,} from 'react-native';
// import all basic components
import QRCode from 'react-native-qrcode-svg';
//import QRCode

class App extends Component {
    svg;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
      inputValue2: '',
      // Default Value of the TextInput
      valueForQRCode: '',
      // Default value for the QR Code
    };
  }

  getTextInputValue = () => {
    // Function to get the value from input
    // and Setting the value to the QRCode
    this.setState({ valueForQRCode: this.state.inputValue + this.state.inputValue2 });
  };
  shareQR =()  =>{
    this.svg.toDataURL((data) => {
      const shareImageBase64 = {
        title: "QR",
        message: "Ehi, this is my QR code",
        url: `data:image/png;base64,${data}`
      };
      Share.open(shareImageBase64);
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <QRCode
          value={"Abhigyan" + this.state.valueForQRCode}
          //Setting the value of QRCode
          size={250}
          //Size of QRCode
          bgColor="#000"
          //Backgroun Color of QRCode
          fgColor="#fff"
          //Front Color of QRCode
          getRef={(ref) => (this.svg = ref)}
          onPress={() =>{shareQR()}}
        />
        <TextInput
          // Input to get the value to set on QRCode
          style={styles.TextInputStyle}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ inputValue: text })}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Enter text to Generate QR Code"
        />

<TextInput
          // Input to get the value to set on QRCode
          style={styles.TextInputStyle}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ inputValue2: text })}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Enter text to Generate QR Code"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.getTextInputValue}
          activeOpacity={0.7}
          style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.TextStyle}> Generate QR Code </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}onPress={this.shareQR}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Share</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
  },

  TextInputStyle: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 40,
    marginTop: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },

  button: {
    width: '100%',
    paddingTop: 8,
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#F44336',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },

  TextStyle: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});
```

//Thanks .
// In QRCode I am able to generate and QRCode scanner both I have done ,but how to download /save or share that qrcode ,Please help

Comment: Note that react-native-qrcode is no longer maintained and seems your request has never been implemented. I suggest you to try react-native-qrcode-svg, works pretty well and you can export the image as png for example

Comment: Thanks .. one more thing for that I need to link that ..??

Comment: Not directly: I mean the library uses react-native-svg, so I should install and link that before you install react-native-qrcode-svg

Comment: ok let me try.. Thanks

Comment: null is not an object (evaluating RNGestureHandlerModule.State) .. getting this error

Comment: Probably you need to manually link react-native-svg: [link](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg#ios)

Comment: May be.. let me try that also

Comment: That error solver.. and qr code generate but now how can i save ,share pr download it ? Please help

Comment: I'll try to explain it in an answer

Comment: Please.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**This answer refers to react-native-qrcode-svg library, as written in the question comments**.

With this library you can create an svg to show the QR you want and then access it by reference. So, create a reference in your component:

```
class App extends Component {
  svg;
  constructor() {
    ...
    };
  }
...
}
```

Assign it the QRCode, for example:

```
<QRCode
  value={"Abhigyan" +this.state.valueForQRCode}
  size={250}
  color="#fff"
  getRef={(ref?) => (this.svg = ref)}
/>
```

Now you can access its content with `this.svg.toDataURL(//callback)`.
Example: you wanna share the QR as an image/png using react-native-share by clicking on a button which calls this function:

```
  shareQR() {
    this.svg.toDataURL((data) => {
      const shareImageBase64 = {
        title: "QR",
        message: "Ehi, this is my QR code",
        url: `data:image/png;base64,${data}`
      };
      Share.open(shareImageBase64);
    });
  }
```

This is just an example, if you prefer to use react-native-fs you can refer to the [example](https://github.com/awesomejerry/react-native-qrcode-svg#example-for-android) given in the official repository.

**Update to support onPress function**

You're trying to pass onPress prop to `QRCode`, but `QRCode` does not support it. Instead, wrap it in a `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shareQR}>
  <QRCode
    value={"Abhigyan" +this.state.valueForQRCode}
    size={250}
    color="#fff"
    getRef={(ref?) => (this.svg = ref)}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I'll try that.. Thanks A lot :)

Comment: getRef={(ref?) -   ?- can only use in .ts file..I have made changes.. May I update my question ? or if won't mind can we chat somewhere ? like LinkedIn or gmail?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot to remove the `?` since I took it from a .ts project I'm working on

Comment: I don't know I am doing correct or not , because on long press nothing is happening ..

Comment: I can't understand the problem without any code, update your answer or try to explain where do you call on long press

Comment: Updated brother .. Basically  on QRCode I want to use that functionality on press ,like when after generating QRCode ,I'll press on that qrcode and then share , but button is also fine but..

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks ..now getting error can't find variable Share "Share.open(shareImageBase64);"

Comment: Got it , I just import Share , so now   its coming .."undefined is not a function (evaluating _reactNative.Share.open(shareImageBase64'))

Comment: Above solves ..
    npm install react-native-share --save
    react-native link react-native-share

Comment: It asked for gallery access option ,but now new exception :)

Comment: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Object.keys(styles)[typeof Symbol ==="function"?Symbol.iterator:"@@iterator"]())

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188393/discussion-between-milore-and-abhigyan-gaurav).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) to create an image of QR code then you can save it in camera roll or disk storage.